# Is there a way to reset a counter in an nftables set?

Tags: nftables

I have a table with a set of ipv4_addr that has a counter for each element.

I want to reset the counters after reading the packets counted, but from what I can tell there is no way to do this.

Are set counters considered anonymous counters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This feature was made available on 2023-07-14, so after this question was asked: it requires [*nftables* 1.0.8](https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-announce/2023/000251.html) and Linux kernel >= 6.5:

> - Support for resetting stateful expressions in sets, maps and elements,   e.g. counters:
>
>   ```
>   reset element t m '{ 1.2.3.4 }'
>   reset map ip t m
>   reset set ip t m
>   ```
>
>   Note that this feature requires Linux kernel >= 6.5-rc1.

Here's a reproducible example within an interactive shell (using nftables 1.0.9 on kernel 6.6):

```shell
$ unshare -Urnm
# nft add table t
# nft add set t s '{ type ipv4_addr; counter; elements = { 192.0.2.1 counter packets 10 bytes 1000, 198.51.100.2 counter packets 20 bytes 2000, 203.0.113.3 counter packets 30 bytes 3000 } }'
# nft reset element t s '{ 198.51.100.2 }'
table ip t {
        set s {
                type ipv4_addr
                elements = { 198.51.100.2 counter packets 20 bytes 2000 }
        }
}
# nft reset set t s
table ip t {
        set s {
                type ipv4_addr
                counter
                elements = { 192.0.2.1 counter packets 10 bytes 1000, 198.51.100.2 counter packets 0 bytes 0,
                             203.0.113.3 counter packets 30 bytes 3000 }
        }
}
# nft list set t s
table ip t {
        set s {
                type ipv4_addr
                counter
                elements = { 192.0.2.1 counter packets 0 bytes 0, 198.51.100.2 counter packets 0 bytes 0,
                             203.0.113.3 counter packets 0 bytes 0 }
        }
}
#
```

- The first reset (`reset element`) displays-and-reset the element `{ 198.51.100.2 }`,
- the 2nd reset (`reset set`) displays-and-reset the whole set with the element `{ 198.51.100.2 }` showing its counter was previously reset,
- finally `list` displays the set with all counters now zeroed.